# Unity3D iTextSharp UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: android

I am making an application in Unity3d, and I am using iTextSharp to make some reports. When I build my app on Android device, I get an error:

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/TestPDF.pdf" is
>   denied

Here is how I create PDF:

```
Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
pageSize.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(242, 218, 157);
Document doc = new Document(pageSize, 10, 10, 40, 40);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("TestPDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
...
doc.Close();
```

I need it to work for Android, iOS, and desktop devices.

Comment: This is not an iText or iTextSharp problem. It's a problem that will also occur if you try to write plain text or bytes to a `FileStream`. The error message informs you that you need to write the PDF file to a location to which you have access. The question should be rephrased as: "Which path can I use to write a file to the file system using Unity3D."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in document path. Here is what I changed:

```
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "TestPDF.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
```